# How to install MS Office in a Docker container with mono?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mono, office365, ms-office

I have an app that requires MS office. This app is docker containerized app and should run on GCP kubernetes cluster. How can i install MS office in a linux docker container?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it requires **MS Office** and not just some related **libraries** ? Is it your custom app or something publicly available on **github** ?

Answer (score 3):

Via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modernize-with-azure-containers/modernize-existing-apps-to-cloud-optimized/when-not-to-deploy-to-windows-containers this was not possible as of April 2018.

Comment: You can follow the thread Function Request here: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/304624-containers/suggestions/19686220-provide-office-support-for-containers

Comment: Were you able to install it eventually? I want to try this solution: https://blog.devgenius.io/install-microsoft-office-in-windows-container-ce05877138fd , but I'm trying to understand which `AWS` instance I need to create for it. how much CPU, Memory, etc...